# Even after entering proper bytes32 value and address value. Setaddress function is not working

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am getting generic error every time I try to modify the code. I am passing `byte32` value as `"0xabcd"` and address value as `"0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c"` in `Setaddress` function.

The error is as below:

> "transact to EternalStorage.setAddress errored: VM error: revert.
>   revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
>   Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.  Debug the transaction to get more information."

Below is my code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
contract EternalStorage {

address owner = msg.sender;
address latestVersion;

mapping(bytes32 => uint) uIntStorage;
mapping(bytes32 => address) addressStorage;

modifier onlyLatestVersion() {
   require(msg.sender == latestVersion);
    _;
}

function upgradeVersion(address _newVersion) public {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    latestVersion = _newVersion;
}

// *** Getter Methods ***
function getUint(bytes32 _key) external view returns(uint) {
    return uIntStorage[_key];
}

function getAddress(bytes32 _key) external view returns(address) {
    return addressStorage[_key];
}

// *** Setter Methods ***
function setUint(bytes32 _key, uint _value) onlyLatestVersion external {
    uIntStorage[_key] = _value;
}

function setAddress(bytes32 _key, address _value) onlyLatestVersion external  payable{
    addressStorage[_key] = _value;
}

// *** Delete Methods ***
function deleteUint(bytes32 _key) onlyLatestVersion external {
    delete uIntStorage[_key];
}

function deleteAddress(bytes32 _key) onlyLatestVersion external {
    delete addressStorage[_key];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that the transaction to `setAddress()` reverted:

> transact to EternalStorage.setAddress errored: VM error: revert.

There is only one `requre()` statement in `setAddress()`, in `onlyLatestVersion()`:

```
require(msg.sender == latestVersion);
```

So it's virtually certain that the sender of the transaction (`msg.sender`) is not set to `latestVersion`. That means you either need to:

1. Make sure you are sending from the account that the contract has as the `latestVersion`, or...
2. Change `latestVersion` using the contract's function `upgradeVersion()`, so that it matches your transaction sender.